# How are these two definitions of being stably $\mathbb{C}_0(S)$-convergent equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, definition, banach-spaces

Below are paragraphs I took from Doob's [Measure Theory](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-1-4612-0877-8.pdf).

---

A function $f$ from a metric space $S$ into a metric space is said to have **limit $\alpha$ at infinity** if the inverse image of each neighborhood of $\alpha$ is contained in the complement of a compact subset of $S$. Let

- $S$ be a metric space,
- $\mathbb M(S)$ the space of all finite signed Borel measures on $S$,
- $\mathbb C(S)$ be the space of real-valued bounded continuous functions on $S$,
- $\mathbb C_0(S)$ be the space of real-valued continuous functions on $S$ with limit $0$ at infinity, and
- $\mathbb C_{00} (S)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions on $S$ with compact supports.

For $E \in \{\mathbb C(S), \mathbb C_0(S), \mathbb C_{00} (S)\}$, a sequence $\lambda_{ \bullet} \subset \mathbb{M}(S)$ is said to be **$E$-convergent** to $\lambda \in \mathbb{M}(S)$ if $\lim \lambda_{ \bullet}[f]=\lambda[f]$ for all $f$ in $E$.

Let $\lambda_{ \bullet}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{M}(S)$ with $\mathbb{C}_0(S)$-limit $\lambda$ in $\mathbb{M}(S)$. The sequence is **stably $\mathbb{C}_0(S)$-convergent** to $\lambda$ if $\lim \lambda_{\bullet}(S)=\lambda(S)$. The point of this strengthening of $\mathbb{C}_0(S)$-convergence is that the sequence of measures is not allowed to unload measure at infinity.

By definition, $\lambda_{ \bullet}$ is **stably $\mathbb{C}_0(S)$-convergent** to $\lambda$ if and only if $\lim \lambda_{ \bullet}[f]=\lambda[f]$, whenever $f$ is in $\mathbb{C}(S)$ and is either identically constant or has limit $0$ at infinity; in other words if and only if $\lim \lambda_{ \bullet}[f]=\lambda[f]$ whenever $f$ is continuous and has a finite limit at infinity.

---

**My understanding:** It seems the author's definition of a function with limit $0$ at infinity coincides with the [usual one](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_vanishing_at_infinity). It seems from above that the following statements are equivalent, i.e.,

1. $\lim \lambda_{ \bullet}[f]=\lambda[f]$ for all $f \in \mathbb{C}_0(S)$ and $\lim \lambda_{\bullet}(S)=\lambda(S)$.
2. $\lim \lambda_{ \bullet}[f]=\lambda[f]$ for all $f \in \mathbb{C}(S)$ that is either constant or has limit $0$ at infinity.
3. $\lim \lambda_{ \bullet}[f]=\lambda[f]$ for all continuous $f$ that is either constant or has a finite limit at infinity.

I understand how 2. is equivalent to 1. and how 3. implies 1.

> Could you explain how 1. implies 3.?

---

**Update:** I think I was wrong in claiming that *"the author's definition of a function with limit $0$ at infinity coincides with the [usual one](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_vanishing_at_infinity)"*. Let $\alpha=0$ and $\varepsilon>0$. Then $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ is a neighborhood of $\alpha$.

- In author's sense: there is a compact subset $K$ of $S$ such that $f^{-1}((-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)) \subset K^c$. This is equivalent to $|f(x)| < \varepsilon \implies x \in K^c$.
- In the [usual](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Function_vanishing_at_infinity) sense: there is a compact subset $K$ of $S$ such that $|f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for all $x \in K^c$. This is equivalent to $|f(x)| \ge \varepsilon \implies x \in K$.

---

For a reference, I attach below a screenshot from the book.

[image]

Comment: @PaulSinclair Maybe I'm wrong, but [$|f(x)| < \varepsilon \implies x \in K^c$] is equivalent to [$x \in K \implies |f(x)| \ge \varepsilon$].

Comment: Sorry. You are right about that.

Comment: I have to believe the author intended the normal definition. Since the empty set is technically compact, the author's definition as stated would imply that for every $\alpha$, every function $f$ would have limit $\alpha$ at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, my question would be why is (3) stated in this fashion, since constant functions are always continuous and always have a finite limit at $\infty$.

If $f$ has a finite limit of $\alpha$ at infinity, then $f = (f - \alpha) + \alpha$. $\alpha$ is a constant function and $f - \alpha$ is continuous with limit $0$ at infinity. Hence, by (1) $$\lim \lambda_*[f - \alpha] = \lambda[f - \alpha]$$
and $$\lim \lambda_*[\alpha] = \alpha\lim \lambda_*(S) = \alpha\lambda(S) = \lambda[\alpha]$$
so
$$\lim \lambda_*[f] = \lim \lambda_*[f - \alpha] +  \lim \lambda_*[\alpha] = \lambda[f - \alpha] + \lambda[\alpha] = \lambda[f]$$