# References for Prokhorov's theorem for finite signed measures on a completely regular space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces, compactness, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal M(X)$ the space of all finite signed Borel measures on $X$. For $\nu \in \mathcal M(X)$, let $(\nu^+, \nu^-)$ be its Jordan decomposition, and $|\nu| := \nu^+ + \nu^-$ its associated variation. We endow $\mathcal M(X)$ with the total variation norm $[\cdot]$ defined by $[\nu] := |\nu|(X)$. Then $(\mathcal M(X), [\cdot])$ is a Banach space.

- A subset $M$ of $\mathcal M(X)$ is said to **tight** if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a compact subset $K$ of $X$ such that $\sup_{\nu \in M}| \nu| (X \setminus K) <\varepsilon$.
- A subset $M$ of $\mathcal M(X)$ is said to **bounded** if $\sup_{\nu \in M} [\nu] <\infty$.

Then I come across this version of Prokhorov's theorem from this French [Wikipedia page](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_de_Prokhorov#G%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralisations).

> **Theorem:** Let $X$ be completely regular and $M$ a subset of $\mathcal M (X)$.
>
> 1. If $M$ tight and bounded, then the closure of $M$ in $\sigma(\mathcal M (X), \mathcal C_b(X))$ is sequentially compact.
> 2. If $X$ is locally compact (*or* Polish) and the closure of $M$ in $\sigma(\mathcal M (X), \mathcal C_b(X))$ sequentially compact, then $M$ is tight and bounded.

This is very general. In Onno van Gaans's lecture note [Probability measures on metric spaces](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/jancol1.pdf), for (1.) to hold, it is assumed further that $X$ is separable.

Could you confirm if above theorem with such a great generality is indeed true? If yes, could you please provide a reference.

Comment: Check Bogachev's Measure theory vol. 2. There are several versions of Prohorov type results and many references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned in that Wikipedia page that Bourbaki (1969) and Jarchow (1981) gave the proof for above generalization.

- Bourbaki, intégration chapitre 9 §5, Springer, 1969.
- Hans Jarchow, Locally convex spaces, Teubner, 1981.